# Google Chrome extension: copying base64 image data from <img> tag on page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to do something very similar to a question that has already been answered here:

[build a chrome extension in order to upload images (from clipboard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546482/build-a-chrome-extension-in-order-to-upload-images-from-clipboard)

but with a significant difference. In the problem above, the developer is taking a screenshot of the a tab via captureVisibleTab(), and uploading the data to a server via a chrome plugin.

What I'm looking for is a way to do the exact same thing except with the content of a single img tag on the visible tab, instead of the whole tab ... is this possible or can I only take a full screenshot?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)` where `img` is a reference to the `<img>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the path to the actual file:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function (e) {
  var base64Data = e.target.result;
};

reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
```

Theoretically you could pull the file from the browser's tmp folder that downloaded that image.