# Upload file not working in Chrome extension option page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, image-uploading

I am developing a chrome extension with an option page. On that page I put an upload image option but can't get the file to load in javascript. I have tried many solutions ([1st solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373834/upload-image-using-javascript), [2nd solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546482/build-a-chrome-extension-in-order-to-upload-images-from-clipboard) ...) but none worked. The strange thing is, that even an "onclick" attribute in the html code doesn't call the corresponding function. Here is an example of the code:

HTML example:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadImage" id="uploadImage" />
<button type="submit" id="imageUpload-btn" onclick="myFunction();">Upload</button>
```

javascript example:

```
jQuery("#imageUpload-btn").click(function(){
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = jQuery("#uploadImage").val();
    alert(image.src);
    image.onload = function(){
        alert("on load");
    }
    image.onerror = function(){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

I get the path of the file in the first alert, but then always the error alert. The function "myFunction()" is not called, but if I open the file directly in a browser the "onclick" trigger works and "myFunction()" is called.

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: The value of a file input is not the actual path to the file (due to browser security). Do you intent to upload this image via ajax?

Comment: If it is possible i would like to upload it with only javascript and save it in chrome.storage. I have tried a code, that stored the image in localStorage (html5, i tjik that it was the one from this page [link](http://robnyman.github.io/html5demos/localstorage/)), but it doesn't work in the option page of the chrome extension, but if i open the option.html file directly in the browser it works fine. It must be something with the

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="Upload" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <p>Filename: <INPUT type="file" name="submitfile" id = "submitfile" />
   <INPUT type="button" value="Send" onClick="checkSize();" />
   </form>
```

here you are using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in this type we dont have opertunity to use

```
 im.src = document.getElementById('submitfile').value;
```

you need to go for apache.commons.fileupload `ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);` which is totally java related.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to make a form and use a server side code (PHP, JSP, ...) to get the POST or GET action, but I need the browser side code with javascript, because i don't have a server and need to upload it on browser side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work within `#uploadImage` because the url of an uploaded file gets mangled.  You want to use something like

```js
jQuery('#uploadImage').change(function(event) {
    const uploadedFile = event.target.files[0];
    // save uploadedFile to chrome.storage
});
```